# GitLab CI Pipeline on specific branch composer: command not found

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to implement GitLab CI Pipelines to build and deploy an app.

In our project we have two branches: master and others.
For a particular branch(eg:p-01-sprint-04), I want to run a Pipeline in order to build the application and deploy the build on a test environment.

The build failed during execution.

This is how my `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like:

```
stages:
  - test

unit_test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - composer install
    - php artisan migrate
    - php artisan db:seed
    - composer require laravel/passport
    - php artisan passport:client --personal
    - php artisan storage:link
    - php artisan serve
```

The build failed with these errors :

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.8.0 (4745a6f3)
  on gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-64c48b5865-wx6wl BS2DZ3GP
Using Kubernetes namespace: gitlab
Using Kubernetes executor with image ubuntu:16.04 ...
Waiting for pod gitlab/runner-bs2dz3gp-project-924-concurrent-0tzq4t to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab/runner-bs2dz3gp-project-924-concurrent-0tzq4t to be running, status is Pending
Running on runner-bs2dz3gp-project-924-concurrent-0tzq4t via gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-64c48b5865-wx6wl...
Cloning into '/mk2/billeterie/bo'...
Cloning repository...
Checking out 841a7daf as p-01-sprint-04...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ composer install
/bin/bash: line 72: composer: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Log shows you use `ubuntu:16.04` with `kubernetes`executor :

```
Using Kubernetes executor with image ubuntu:16.04 ...
```

`composer` is not installed in `ubuntu:16.04` docker image.

Use `composer` [image](https://hub.docker.com/_/composer) instead which provide `php`and `composer` binaries.

Comment: Could you please guide me how to change it into  composer image

Comment: specify `image: composer` just below `unit_test:` in your gitlab-ci.yml